# how to create flv videoframe from h.264 AAC samples in mp4

Tags: flv, h.264, mp4, frames, aac

I have a mp4 file which has only mdat box(h.264, aac) and I can specify the video samples. I need to convert video samples to flv frames, how can be done?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using ffmpeg.

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 out.flv
```